# Emulate bluetooth devices inside of docker

Tags: docker, security, bluetooth

I'm new to the cybersucurity scene and I'm teaching myself through projects.

One is hacking bluetooth devices like speakers or cameras, but I don't have those devices present. However, I thought that Docker could solve that issue because I used it with AWS and knew how powerful it is.

How can I emulate a bluetooth device for hacking using Docker? An existing solution would be much appreciated since I don't think I posses to skillset to do it from scratch, but I'm grateful for any guidance!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Docker doesn't "emulate devices"; it reuses the host kernel and has a limited operator-controlled ability to republish host devices into a container.  Are you looking for a full virtual machine setup that can do this, or to build an emulated Bluetooth kernel driver that could run on your EC2 instance?

Comment: I would want to do anything can can make a fake bluetooth device, that I can practice on. I was thinking of taking an open source bluetooth driver and stripping it of the real interaction and replace with my own, I just don't know where to begin with that